# Store method in hidden field in form

Tags: php, javascript

this is properly a very simple question but whatever:

why does the following not work?

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="value" value="return $(\"#compare_bd\").mergely(\"get\", rhs)">';
```

it returns: `return $(//`

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't know that you want to run javascript. Instead PHP is trying to parse the data. Try adding `javascript: ` before the `return` and see what happens.

Comment: mmh, then it just outputs: javascript:return $(\\

Comment: Because then your result is value="return $(" , and to HTML that is the end of an attribute. Consider using '.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can't you just rewrite it do to this:

PHP Page:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="value" id="someField" value="">';
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#someField').val($("#compare_bd").mergely("get", rhs));
});
```

Comment: What do you mean empty output?

Comment: when i check $_POST['value'] at the page where to form goes to, it is NULL

Comment: You were right the whole time, i just had to put 'rhs' instead of just rhs

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="value" value="return $(\'#compare_bd\').mergely(\'get\', rhs)">';
```

When php prints your code as html you get:

```
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="return $("#compare_bd").mergely("get", rhs)">
```

That is not valid html.

So in my case it will print:

```
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="return $('#compare_bd').mergely('get', rhs)">
```

Comment: mmh, still giving me: return $\\